# Highstock - Using a heatmap with a ColorAxis gets: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: highcharts, heatmap

I'm trying to use a ColorAxis in a Heatmap from Highstock and I get an `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` every time I hover over the heatmap. In another case, I get the same error but the heatmap doesn't even render. If I remove the ColorAxis settings from the initialization of the chart, there aren't any issues.

An example of a fiddle where this happens: http://jsfiddle.net/ee6r6wwr/ (this example was forked from another fiddle for a SO answer but I replaced Highcharts with Highstock)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks related to this issue: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3360. `axes` variable is not getting initialized.

Comment: And it's fixed on master branch: http://jsfiddle.net/ee6r6wwr/1/